# Importing typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular-cli

I'm using [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create a web application and am having trouble importing the [facebook type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts).  Specifically they declare this:

```
interface Window{
    fbAsyncInit() : any;
}

declare module "FB" {
    export = FB;
}

declare var FB : FBSDK;
```

In my app src directory I have `app/services/facebook/facebook.ts` with this:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {FB} from './../../types/fbsdk.d.ts';
```

And the facebook definitions in a new types directory I created: `app/types/fbsdk.d.ts`.  The error I get when compiling is:

```
File 'app/types/fbsdk.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I've tried a few other things but haven't found any that work.

---

***EDIT***

I got Visual Studio Code to recognize the types and the compile to work, but when the app reloads it attempts to access `/FB` which gives a 404 error because it doesn't exist.  All the modules I've created are accessed in a relative directory where the typescript files were, for instance the Facebook module is retrieved from `/app/services/facebook/facebook.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the compiler about the declaration file by adding this to your TypeScript code:

```
/// <reference path='./../../types/fbsdk.d.ts'/>
```

Then you can import the FB module with a statement like `import {Something} from "FB"` or `import * as FB from "FB"`.

Comment: Ah, all I had to do was add the reference and *not* do the import.  Thanks!